# Auto refresh scope every 15 sec with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need help w my code, i want to refresh the scope of my list without refreshing the page, just the scope, i need to refresh it every 15 seconds, can somebody help me?

```
$scope.getAllTickets = function () {
    $scope.listAllTickets = [];
    $timeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Chamados/GetAllTickets',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                $scope.listAllTickets = result;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                toastr.error("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar os dados.", "Tickets");
            }
        });
    },
        500);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out how to do it, if someone needs a answer for a problem like mine, ill leave the code here

```
function refreshScope() {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.getAllTickets();
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 15000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give you the result you want.

```js
$scope.getAllTickets = function () {
    $scope.listAllTickets = [];
    var func = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Chamados/GetAllTickets',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                $scope.listAllTickets = result;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                toastr.error("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar os dados.", "Tickets");
            }
        });
    };
    $interval(func, 15000);
}
```